# how to convert jsf PrimeFaces into bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, jsf, primefaces

How to convert java server face  prime face into bootstrap?. The project has already developed in java server face. I need to change the view responsive.

Comment: PrimeFaces is already responsive, if you do it correctly.

Comment: but i should convert it to bootstrap only

Comment: i want view in bootstrap. plz help me boss

Comment: I want money, care to exchange? And you cannot remove just the view. Jsf is an mvc.

Comment: k...i will give u.........but i need solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

You already can use some bootstrap CSS classes and helpers but if you want give style to each UI control, you will need to set the primefaces theme to none.

```
<context-param> <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name> <param-value>none</param-value> </context-param>
```

Then you will need to give some style to each component you want. Just using the corresponding classes in each one of the components.

Comment: i need some step by step solution. bcause this is new thing for me. i knw only bootstrap . but i dnt knw jsf primeface

Comment: And why not reccommend to add the bootstrap theme then?

Comment: You have to add the bootstrap library to your template. But there is not a bootstrap theme for primefaces.